# Determine the min/max resistance of an SMD variable resistor

Tags: resistors, voltage-regulator, buck, variable

I want to **determine my minimum and maximum resistance rating for my variable resistor** but failed to find the relevant information in the datasheet (this might be an issue more 'noobs' might have, therefore the question here).

1. I chose a SMD **Variable Resistor** ([LCSC link](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Variable-Resistors-Potentiometers_HDK-Hokuriku-Elec-Industry-VG039NCHXTB153_C128547.html)) **rated at 15kΩ** because it's close to the desired range (24-33kΩ), and because it's assembled by JLCPCB (and in stock).
2. Where in the **datasheet** ([link](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810170719_HDK-Hokuriku-Elec-Industry-VG039NCHXTB153_C128547.pdf)) do I find the minimum and maximum resistance, approximately (standard environment)?
3. (Are there general 'rule-of-thumbs' for variable resistors when it comes to min/max resistance ratings?)

**Background (to avoid [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))**: 
I want to regulate 3.7-5V -> 3.3V (either from lipo or usb port), I determined [STI3408B](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2007241904_TMI-STI3408B_C708874.pdf) is a good choice: it provides up to 1.2A and has a somewhat low quiescent current of '40µA' (I'm sure that's variable depending on multiple factors I'm currently unaware of) and it doesn't have the thermal issues as linear regulators. Using a similar component, I *measured my reference voltage to be around 0.7V (using off-the-shelf multimeter), not 0.6V* as in the datasheet. I'm unsure if (or why) this is really an issue, but to minimize the potential of errors (that require re-soldering), I concluded a *variable* resistor for `R2` would be suitable, the formula to determine the output of the IC seems to be fairly standard (see below), where `Vout` is between `2.6-3.6V` (esp32) and I planned `R1` to be `110kΩ`.

 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a 15k potentiometer, ideally it will have exactly 15k resistance between ends, and when the wiper is at one end, there will b 0 ohms between wiper and end, and of course 15k from wiper to the other end.

But components are never ideal.

The datasheet says that the resistance is 15k with a tolerance of 25%.

And the wiper to end resistance is 2% from the 15k at most.

Comment: oh, so the rating always references the maximum resistance... that makes sense, thank you. The tolerance of 25% is specified, I took note. Thank you for the kind answer

Comment: No, not always. The datasheet says for potentiometers above 1k it is 2% of the total, but for pots less than 1k it is 20 ohms max.

Comment: I'll scan the datasheet for this, simply couldn't extract what you just mentioned

Comment: clearly, if I want to reach e.g. 35kOhm, I'll need a higher-rated variable resistor

Comment: And then there is the contact resistance rating too, but it may not be important to you.

Comment: Yes, you would not buy a 15k pot if you need 35k. You would buy a 47k pot.

Comment: I don't really know about it, I just need a crude way to change the resistance in the circuit, alternativly I'll just use mutliple resistors amd break/cut lines on the board